# How does this affect the slope

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

This is a Linear regression question, where I have a list of values for Sales ($Y$) and Property ($X$), I have calculated the Mean for both $Y$ and $X$, resulting in $Y=52.2$and $X=17$, I have calculated the Slope for this which is $m=2.5$ and the intercept $b=5.7$,

Question is suppose that for each $\$2$ of extra sales gives me $\$1$ of extra profit. How large would the slope need to be to make the product placement expenditure worth it?

I assume we are dealing with a break-even situation here?

A Sample of what I think I'm looking for is [here](http://www2.owen.vanderbilt.edu/Germain.Boer/mgt413/cvp/cvp.html)

Explaining this in more detail:

If  the slope is 1, then if I spend $\$1.00$ on advertising I get $\$1.00$ extra revenue but only $50%$ or $0.50 is extra profit. So my net position is `-$1.00$+$0.50` so I am behind.

If the slope is 5, then if I spend $\$1.00$ on advertising I get $\$5.00$ extra revenue but only $50%$ or $2.50 is extra profit. So my net position is `-$1.00+$2.50` so I am in front.

If the slope is 2.5, then if I spend $\$1.00$ on advertising I get $\$2.50$ extra revenue but only $50%$ or $1.25 is extra profit. So my net position is `-$1.00+$1.25` so I am in front.

What value for the slope makes me break even?

Comment: I don't understand your question. So you have a linear equation $f(x) = 2.5x + 5.7$. What is this a model of?

Comment: Y or f(x) stands for Sales and x stands for Property, the values for Y and x are:

Y=52.2
X=17

With the current slope in mind, if the $2$ of extra sales does hive me $1$ of extra profit, I want to know how this will effect the current slope?

Please let me know if this doesnt make sense..

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Could you update the question (edit it) and explain a bit more about what is given and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I have updated the Question, I hope I have explained it in a more detailed fashion.